# Нужна ли запятая перед "как" в данном случае?

Tags: запятые, союзы, как

А я ведь гость, так что (?) как я могу тут хозяйничать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно, запятая здесь не нужна, ибо "так что" - это обычный подчинительный союз следствия, которым начинается придаточное предложение